# Regex to remove <br> tag from the beginning of string using ColdFusion

Tags: regex, coldfusion

I want to get rid of any `<br>`, `<br />`, or `<br/>` tag from the start of the string using regex in ColdFusion.

Initial Text -

```
<br /><br>Philosophy Now is a lively and readable magazine for everyone interested in ideas. 
<br> This is a test
```

Final text -

```
Philosophy Now is a lively and readable magazine for everyone interested in ideas. 
<br> This is a test
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Use this `^<br\s*\/><br>` regex and replace the match with an empty string.

Comment: @AvinashRaj the / in /> is also optional.

Answer (score -1):

I guess this will help you.

```
<cfscript>
    str = "<br/><br /><br  /> <html><br><br>test<br>test<br>";
    str = REReplaceNoCase(str,"^(<.*?>|\s*)*","","All");
    writedump(str);
</cfscript>
```

Comment: Will It only remove from the beginning of the string or entire string?

Comment: entire string. Do you want to remove tags from start of the line but not from rest of the line?

Comment: Yes only from the start

Comment: There is no need to use a loop for this operation.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure you need a regex for this @nasaa - Your example really just needs to strip everything after the last r>. Is it that predictable? How many variations are there?  You could simply do somthign like.

```
<cfset mystring = right(mystring,len(mystring-find(mystring,"r>")+1))/>
```

It might need to be +2 (I always have to tweak it) but you get  the idea.

Of course if it's not that predictable then Regex is probably the way to go. I always have difficulty with regex as well no matter how many times I use it. The sytax is just hairy :)

Comment: There are three problems with this unfortunately. It makes no account `<br/>` or <br />`, it looks for a `r>` and doesn't care where it finds it. There's nothing stopping it from picking it up later in the string, and it only replaces one `<br>`. I don't think this can be done without regex.

Comment: not exactly. It finds the _first_ one. If the string does not have a prepended line break then you are correct, so you would add an if statement... maybe run 2 versions - one looking for r> and one looking for />. See what I mean?  Also this code does _not_ only replace <br> - it actually takes everything _after_ the line breaks - so (again in your example) it would result in the string you are looking for.

Comment: What if the string is `"I like apples<br>and oranges"`? It would remove that linebreak, but what if it was `"<br><br>I like apples<br><br>and oranges"`? It would remove only one <br>. Or am I wrong?

Comment: you are correct - which is why my answer says that the string in play must be "predictable."  If there are only 2 or three patterns you can search for them in a systematic fashion til you get what you want. But again if you have no clue as to how predictable it is. If there can be 5 line breaks or 7 or none or 3 or whatever, then this is probably not going to work. Your question made it sound like you were solving a very specific predictable problem.

Answer (score -1):

This removes `<br>` and `<br />` as many times as it might appear at the beginning of the text. It also removes leading white space, but no other white space.

```
<cfset mystring="<br /><br>Philosophy Now is a lively and readable magazine for everyone interested in ideas. 
<br> This is a test">
<cfset myreplace=ReReplaceNoCase(mystring,"^[   ]*(<br[ \/]*>[   ]*)*[  ]*","","ALL")>
```

### Edit: This answer is incorrectly rated down

Test this code at http://www.cflive.net

```
<cfset mystring="<br /><br>Philosophy Now is a lively and readable magazine for everyone interested in ideas. 
<Br> This is a test">
<cfset myreplace=ReReplaceNoCase(mystring,"^[   ]*(<br[ \/]*>[   ]*)*[  ]*","","ALL")>

<cfoutput><textarea rows="10" cols="50">#mystring#</textarea><br /><br />
  <textarea rows="10" cols="50">#myreplace#</textarea></cfoutput>
```

Comment: Minus 1.  The question states "start of the string".  This is repeated in the comments to another answer.

Comment: @Dan Run the code, it works, it picks up only at the start of the string, or as I said "beginning of the string". I went further and showed the asker how to simultaneously remove leading whitespace. The ^ as the first character of my regex signifies that it only matches linebreaks at the beginning of the string.

Comment: @DanBracuk I'd really love to see a sample string where the code above doesn't work. I did conceive one and altered my regex to accomodate for that ("<br> <br><br />" at the beginning of a string wouldn't remove the second and third, because of the space, if he didn't use the space-trimming version.)